# Flash speeds the timeline when using gotoandstop, how to work around?

Tags: performance, actionscript-3, flash, debugging, actionscript

We have a certain element, a movieclip that contains a small (124x124) FLV wrapped in a movieclip on every frame that loops. There are about 105 of these movieclips on every frame.

The problem i have is that every time i change frame in the movieclip using gotoandstop() the rest of the SWF play all timelines at a very high speed. **This is how it looks in Scout:** [image: Scout]

As you can see it speeds up to around 5000-800 fps to the gotoandstop has seeked through the entire movieclip.

What am i doing wrong? Is this just how Flash works when seeking through a movieclip or am i doing something wrong?

This is how it looks when i am not seeking:
[image: Usual]

Comment: Once you `gotoAndStop()` do a repeated `trace(stage.frameRate)`, it's possible that the FLV player changes this value unbeknownst to you.

Comment: Tried that, stage reports a solid 60 FPS sadly :(